# Is there a pattern/cleaner way of saving a large object with multiple nested classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net

I'm in the midst of a rather large project which involves decomposing a very old and large ColdFusion legacy application and creating some .NET services in it's place. Due to this, there are some requirements I'm not a huge fan of that it needs to support as we transition to this new backend. One of these requirements is a single endpoint that must take a very large JSON payload with many optional/required subclasses and save it all in one go.

I've broken down this data into a rather large domain object and various nested subclasses, and save each subclass in a transaction if it is included in the request.

The code looks something like this:

```
    using (var transaction = await _transactionFactory.CreateDbTransactionScopeAsync(token))
    {

        //save basic patient info 
        newPatient = await _patientRepo.CreatePatientAsync(request, transaction, token);

        //save patient medicare information
        if (request.PatientMedicare != null)
            newPatient.PatientMedicare = await _patientRepo.CreatePatientMedicareAsync(newPatient.Id, request.PatientMedicare, transaction, token);

        //save patient flags
        if (request.PatientFlags != null)
            newPatient.PatientFlags = await CreatePatientFlagsAsync(newPatient.Id, request.PatientFlags, transaction, token);

        //save patient code
        if (request.PatientCode != null)
            newPatient.PatientCode = await _patientRepo.CreatePatientCodeAsync(newPatient.Id, request.PatientCode, transaction, token);

        //save patient facilities
        if (request.PatientFacilities != null)
            newPatient.PatientFacilities = await CreatePatientFacilitiesAsync(newPatient.Id, request.PatientFacilities, transaction, token);

       ... etc (this goes on for 15+ subclasses)
```

If I could avoid having to do this I would but until we are able to re-write more of this ColdFusion front end code this is really the only option.

**Is there a pattern or something that would make this a little cleaner? Something like a builder or factory pattern but that handles saving as opposed to creation/instantiation of an object?**

This is going to be a common issue I deal with with other domain objects a cleaner way to approach this would be awesome.

Comment: Have a look at graphql.

Comment: How are these being stored? Does each repository method call represent a stored procedure or some kind of EF update? Do you have the freedom to change the methods or do you still need to call each one of them separately somehow?

Comment: @JohnWu Yes, each Repo method calls a simple insert stored procedure. I do have the freedom to change such methods, so if you have an idea that goes a different way then feel free to let me know!